# Determine if one of three fields has any of a list of keywords

Tags: c#, string, list, contains

Say we have a model

```
public Foo 
{
    string Something {get;set;}
    string SomethingElse {get;set;}
    string AnotherThing {get;set;}
}
```

What is the most concise way of determining if any of those fields contain any string from a `List`?

```
var foo = new Foo 
{
    Something = "If Liverpool don't beat Fulham this evening I will cry",
    SomethingElse = "I hope I have that TekPub membership for Xmas",
    AnotherThing = "I wish NCrunch was a bit cheaper"
};

var keywords = new List<string> { "Liverpool", "glosrob", "stackoverflow" };
```

Would pass on `foo.Something` containing the word 'Liverpool'.

Comment: Please remember to tag your questions with the relevant language(s). I fixed this one for you, but I'd hope that a 2k+ rep user knows how to get it right the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var entriesSet = new HashSet<string>(foo.Something.Split());
entriesSet.UnionWith(foo.SomethingElse.Split());
entriesSet.UnionWith(foo.AnotherThing.Split());

if (entriesSet.Overlaps(keywords)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
new[] { foo.Something, foo.SomethingElse, foo.AnotherThing }.Any(s => keywords.Any(w => s.Contains(w)))
```